# Linear Function Word Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have the question;

You have decided to purchase a new Honda for 25,635. You have promised your daughter that the car will be hers when the car is worth 10,000. According to your car dealer, the SUV will depreciate in value approximately $3000 per year.

I'm not very good with word problems and my instructor has tried explaining how to do these but I'm just not getting how to go about this.The part I'm stuck on is the first part of the question.

" a) Write a linear equation in winch "y" represents the total value of the car and "X" represents the age of the car."

so far I have y= 25635-x*3000 This is wrong I'm sure but I'm totally lost.

Comment: Your equation expressing the value of the car as a function of its age looks fine to me.

Comment: What makes you think it is wrong ?

Comment: I guess I can't see how I can use this to answer the rest of this question so I assume I must be making a mistake. The part I'm confused with is.

If your daughter is currently 15 years old, how old will she be when the car will be hers?

Answer (score 1):

Your linear function is completely right.
$$y = -3000x+25635$$
Now, to solve for the daughter’s age in years, simply substitute $10000$ for $y$ and solve for $x$, then add the result to $15$.
$$y = 10000 \implies 10000 = -3000x+25635 \implies -15635 = -3000x \implies x = \frac{-15635}{-3000} \implies \boxed{x = 5.211\overline{6}}$$
$$15+5.211\overline{6} = \boxed{20.211\overline{6}}$$
Converting $20.211\overline{6}$ years into years and days, we get $20$ years and $77$ days.

Answer (score 0):

$$25635-3000 t=10000\iff t=5.211666\cdots$$ which is five years and seventy-seven days.